# Error while deploying flask app on apache

Tags: python, apache, flask, wsgi

I have a file manage.py,

```
import os
from app import create_app
app = create_app(os.getenv('FLASK_CONFIG') or 'default')
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

manage.py is working fine when tested in debug mode. However, I'm not able to host it on apache.

**my wsgi file: start.wsgi**

```
from manage import app as application
import sys
sys.stdout = sys.stderr
```

**virtual host:**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName domain.com
   WSGIDaemonProcess manage user=user group=user threads=5
   WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/apioflifeapp/app/start.wsgi
   <Directory /var/www/apioflifeapp/app>
        Require all granted
        Options all
        AllowOverride all
        Allow from all
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**error in error log**

```
 [Sat Feb 21 10:55:47.329450 2015] [:error] [pid 25422] [client 197.226.128.204:56062]   File "/var/www/apioflifeapp/app/start.wsgi", line 1, in <module>
    [Sat Feb 21 10:55:47.329601 2015] [:error] [pid 25422] [client 197.226.128.204:56062]     from manage import app as application
    [Sat Feb 21 10:55:47.329624 2015] [:error] [pid 25422] [client 197.226.128.204:56062] ImportError: No module named manage
```

i'm not understanding why i'm getting the import error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import the app name from your actual application, not `manage`. Assuming it's `apioflifeapp`, you would import the following in *start.wsgi* instead:

```
from apioflifeapp import app as application
```