# Error: ImportError while deploying Flask app in wsgi file

Tags: python, apache, flask, mod-wsgi, wsgi

I dont know what exactly am I missing. Here is what I have till now:

**wsgi**

`/opt/tools/apps/scheduler/scheduler.wsgi`

Its content

```
from scheduler import app as application
```

**init.py**

`/opt/tools/apps/scheduler/scheduler/__init__.py`

**Error in Apache Log**

```
[Thu Feb 04 21:54:30 2016] [error] [client 10.57.136.99] mod_wsgi (pid=45485): Target WSGI script '/opt/tools/apps/scheduler/scheduler.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Thu Feb 04 21:54:30 2016] [error] [client 10.57.136.99] mod_wsgi (pid=45485): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/opt/tools/apps/scheduler/scheduler.wsgi'.
[Thu Feb 04 21:54:30 2016] [error] [client 10.57.136.99] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Thu Feb 04 21:54:30 2016] [error] [client 10.57.136.99]   File "/opt/tools/apps/scheduler/scheduler.wsgi", line 1, in <module>
[Thu Feb 04 21:54:30 2016] [error] [client 10.57.136.99]     from scheduler import app as application
[Thu Feb 04 21:54:30 2016] [error] [client 10.57.136.99] ImportError: No module named scheduler
```

**wsgi.conf**

`/etc/httpd/conf.d`

```
LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so
WSGIPythonHome /opt/tools
WSGISocketPrefix run/wsgi

WSGIDaemonProcess scheduler user=abcd group=efgh processes=4
WSGIScriptAlias /scheduler /opt/tools/apps/scheduler/scheduler.wsgi
<Directory /opt/tools/apps/scheduler>
  WSGIProcessGroup scheduler
  WSGIApplicationGroup %{RESOURCE}
  Order deny,allow
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```

I followed [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28645391/error-while-deploying-flask-app-on-apache) & [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3696606/how-to-solve-import-errors-while-trying-to-deploy-flask-using-wsgi-on-apache2) but no luck. This application was working properly on one host (say *host-1*) and I am trying to deploy it on say *host-2*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your application will run as a daemon, the root directory will be set to `/`.

Ensure your project directory is added to python `PATH` or to let wsgi run the application in the correct path.

Your `scheduler.wsgi` should be something like:

```
# insert application path in python path
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "/opt/tools/apps/scheduler")

# launch app
from scheduler import app as application
```

Also ensure apache user/group (`www-data`) have access to the project:

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /opt/tools/apps/scheduler
```

Comment: Changed `scheduler.wsgi` as above and the permissions is similar to to what's there on `host-1`. :(  But it didnt work. Do you want some more info?

Comment: Put a `import os; print(os.getcwd())` at the top of your wsgi script and show what apache log returns.